# swift array won't contain instance variables

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,     UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIBarButtonItem
var statusLabel: UILabel  = UILabel()
var bottomBar : UIToolbar = UIToolbar()


var globeIcon : UIImage = UIImage(named: "globe-hover.png")
@IBOutlet var captureButton : UIBarButtonItem
@IBOutlet var libraryButton : UIBarButtonItem


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.statusLabel.text="viewDidLoad() called"
    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: self.globeIcon, style: .Plain , target: self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode")
    self.captureButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Take Photo", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "captureClicked")
    self.libraryButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Library", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "libraryClicked")

    self.statusLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.statusLabel.sizeToFit()



   var barItems : [UIBarButtonItem] = [self.nextKeyboardButton, self.captureButton, self.libraryButton]

    self.bottomBar.items = barItems
    self.view.addSubview(self.bottomBar)
    self.view.addSubview(self.statusLabel)



    var statusLabelLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.statusLabel, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    var statusLabelBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.statusLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.view.addConstraints([statusLabelLeftSideConstraint, statusLabelBottomConstraint])





}
```

Each time I run this I get a runtime error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" refering to the bit `var barItems : [UIBarButtonItem] = [self.nextKeyboardButton, self.captureButton, self.libraryButton]` and the debugger states that `barItems` is an empty array (nil).

What's going on here? Why is the array barItems not holding my instance UIBarButtonItem variables? It seems that the UIBarButtonItem type variables (captureButton, libraryButton and nextKeyboardButton) are nil themselves, but why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: To make your barItems array accept nil values change the type to `[UIBarButtonItem?]`. You will then need to explicitly check each array item to see if it is nil before using it by using the `if let concreteItem = barItems[n] { . code when  not nil . } else { . code when nil . }` construct.

Comment: Hint: Create the array in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 1):

Many objects that come from objective C are implicitly unwrapped optionals due to the fact that objective C pointers do not have the same type safety provided by swift.

You are getting the error on this line because the type `[UIBarButtonItem]` does not allow nil values in the array and some of the values you are putting in the array *are* `nil`.

```
var barItems : [UIBarButtonItem] = [self.nextKeyboardButton, self.captureButton, self.libraryButton]
```

The first thing I'd do to make debugging simpler is add types to the original instantiation of these values (which you would *not* expect to be `nil`):

```
self.nextKeyboardButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: self.globeIcon, style: .Plain , target: self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode")
self.captureButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Take Photo", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "captureClicked")
self.libraryButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Library", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "libraryClicked")
```

Some initializers in objective-c return nil to indicate that initialization failed, perhaps this is the case here? If it is, you will get a different error once you add the type annotations. Could you post *that* error?

Comment: After doing some tests the initializers of the items are certainly returning `nil` causing all the problems. After instantiating them before the viewDidLoad() method, I got the errors `'viewController.Type' does not have a member named 'globeIcon'` and `Missing argument for parameter 'landscapeImagePhone' in call` for the second and third UIBarButtonItems. After checking documentation, I should not have to supply that argument so I don't understand what's wrong there. I also don't understand the issues with globeIcon. Any insight?

Comment: I got that "Missing argument for parameter 'landscapeImagePhone' in call" when I was wrongly assigning a [UIBarButtonItem] to navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem (instead of rightBarButtonItems), duh!